# Query a list in mongo

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a mongo collection 'Student' with below documents

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ccc2cded71acf061de1c2d8"),
    "studentId" : "123",
    "name" : "1",
    "age" : NumberLong(0),
    "section" : "A",
    "state" : "State1",
    "city" : "City1"
}
```

I have 100 documents with the above structure. Now i have a list with below structure

```
[{
    "studentId": "123",
    "state": "state1"
},
{
    "studentId": "456",
    "state": "state2"
}]
```

Is there any way in mongo that i can get the documents matching this list data in single db call. Iterating over list with criteria as `studentId:123` and `state:state1` will work but is how to get all list data without iterating in java?

Answer (score 1):

All you need is a simple find query:

```
db.collection.find({$or: arr});
```

when arr is the sample array you showed.

You should note that mongo searches are case sensitive meaning with the sample array you gave no matches will be found since `"state1"` is not equal to `"State1"`.